# Can you add onChange, onBlur and other events to children in React?

Tags: reactjs, children

Is there a way to add additional functionality to children? Not just pass some state but pass actual event functions.

```
function FormField({ children }) {
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);

  return (
    <FormGroup>
      {children}
      <Line />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate. You can provide some code to support your question/requirements.

Comment: Done. How can I pass an onBlur here, is there a way?

Comment: It is still unclear, pass onBlur where? What are these `children`? Are they components?

Comment: children in this case will be an input, or a textarea

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React.Children.map](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildrenmap) to iterate `children` and use [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to add additional props, including event handlers.

```
const onBlur = () => console.log('blur');

return (
  <FormGroup>
    {React.Children.map(
      children,
      c => React.cloneElement(c, { onBlur })
    )}
    <Line />
  </FormGroup>
);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use React.cloneElement to add props to the children component you're getting, here's the example.

```
function FormField({ children }) {
  const [isFocused, setIsFocused] = useState(false);

  return (
    <FormGroup>
      {React.cloneElement(children,{
        onChange: yourFn
      })}
      <Line />
    </FormGroup>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code as image. Copy and paste the code within the post itself.

Comment: i've just edited the answer.